# How do I only display an image if it exists?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am pretty new to php and having a little trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong. For some reason `kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-3', 'post' );` dose not exists (even though It upload and looks fine in the word press admin panel) so it dose not = true and it will not display.

The goal is to display featured-image-3 of all the child pages **only if** featured-image-3 exists ( I am using this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-featured-images/installation/) to have multiple featured images). My method is as follows

1. Get current page ID
2. Us current page ID to query child pages
3. If there are child pages setup post data for each child page
4. Check to see if the child page has featured-image-3
5. If child page has featured_image-3 **display it** : If not **query next post**

**Code in customPage.php**

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) {  /* Query and display the parent. */
while ( have_posts() ) {
the_post();
the_content();
$thispage=$post->ID;
}
```

} ?>

```
<?php $childpages = query_posts('post_type=page&post_parent='.$thispage);
if($childpages) /* display the children content  */
        foreach ($childpages as $post) :
        setup_postdata($post); 
            if (kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-3', 'post' )) {

                    kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-3', 'post' );
                    the_post_thumbnail();

            } 
            else {
                $wp_query->next_post();
            } 


        endforeach; ?>
```

**Code in Functions.php**

```
if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {

    $args2 = array(
            'id' => 'featured-image-2',
            'post_type' => 'page',      // Set this to post or page
            'labels' => array(
                'name'      => 'Home Page Carousel',
                'set'       => 'Set Home Page Carousel',
                'remove'    => 'Remove Home Page Carousel',
                'use'       => 'Use as Home Page Carousel',
            )
    );

    $args3 = array(
            'id' => 'featured-image-3',
            'post_type' => 'page',      // Set this to post or page
            'labels' => array(
                'name'      => 'Product Category Hero',
                'set'       => 'Set Product Category Hero',
                'remove'    => 'Remove Product Category Hero',
                'use'       => 'Use as Product Category Hero',
            )
    );

    $args4 = array(
            'id' => 'featured-image-4',
            'post_type' => 'page',      // Set this to post or page
            'labels' => array(
                'name'      => 'Product Category Featured',
                'set'       => 'Set Product Category Featured',
                'remove'    => 'Remove Product Category Featured',
                'use'       => 'Use as Product Category Featured',
            )
    );

    new kdMultipleFeaturedImages( $args2);
    new kdMultipleFeaturedImages( $args3 );
    new kdMultipleFeaturedImages( $args4 );
```

}

Comment: What's going wrong exactly? You've not said what the problem is

Comment: Sorry... I have edited the post. The questions is how di I make `if (kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-3', 'post' ))`  = true so the content inside the if will display.

Comment: I'm guessing you've already followed all of the steps [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-featured-images/installation/)? My first thought is that maybe the image doesn't exist, so you're seeing exactly the right behaviour - maybe because you've not properly defined or named it

Comment: You are right. the image does not exist. It upload and looks fine in the word press admin panel. Could it be something in my functions.php file? I have updated my question the reflect this new information.